# How to change the background with javascript using an event listener

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-listener

This is my HTML and Javascript, I decided not to include my CSS as don't think its needed. The purpose for my code is to create a toggle switch (like an iPhone setting in the settings app) then to add an event listener using javascript. I made the Listener apply to the button element. When I click on the button, the function, start(), should activate and as you can see, the toggle function should activate when the onclick event is initiated. Which should change the background color when the button is pressed. However, it simply does not change color. Its like the toggle call is not working. I could call the toggle function separately but this changes the color when the page loads. It should work when I click the button. Thank you for anyone that can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Light Switch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" />
</head>

<body id="body">

  <button id="submit">Submit
    <label id="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </button>
  <script src="light.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


//This js file was separate from my HTML file and was linked

function start() {
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  submit.addEventListener("onclick", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("body");
  color.style.backgroundColor = "black";
};

start();
```

Comment: The event name is "click", not "onclick".

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know that onclick is also an event. My programming instructor told us to us to use onclick. And in the devtools window, it shows that the onclick event was added. I will try the click event tho, to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: [Your programming instructor is wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click); it's "click".

Comment: He was talking about the onclick event in HTML. But that does not work in JavaScript, the equivalent to onclick is click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onclick` to only `click`.Also there seems to be no need of the `start()` function in this case.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", toggle);


function toggle() {
  console.log('c')
  document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "black";
};
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <button id="submit">Submit
    <label id="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </button>
</body>
```

Also to use `onclick` you don't need `addEventListener`

```js
var getSubmitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
getSubmitButton.onclick = toggle;

function toggle() {
  document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "black";
};
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <button id="submit">Submit
    <label id="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: I changed onclick to click and it did work. I dont understand why my web programming instructor told us to use onclick. But thank you for the help. Is there any way that onclick will work? I know that it is event, ive used it before to initiate a game I coded in javascript

Comment: Damn, i got unlucky, its my instructors first year teaching and it shows lol. He was chilling with me for 30 mins and he couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @programming__God if you this answer is helpful , please accept it as answer by clicking the tick mark.I will remian obliged to you